# calculate age from two dates

Tags: c#

This part works fine in postgresql and I got exact result

```
SELECT date_part('year', age(CAST(dateofdeath AS timestamp),CAST(dateofbirth AS timestamp) )) FROM tblpersonel WHERE personid=12897
```

But when I put the code in c#

```
string.sql = "SELECT date_part('year', age(CAST(dateofdeath AS timestamp),CAST(dateofbirth AS timestamp) )) FROM tblpersonel WHERE personid ilike '" + txtpersonid.Text + "'::text[]";
                    
cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con); 
NpgsqlDataReader vjen = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

1. List item

at this point I got an error:

> (Npgsql.PostgresException: '22P02: malformed array literal: "16403")

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Your statement in C# has random text in it. Maybe a copy and paste error. In any case, print the statement you have in C# and execute it in your sql client and you will get the same error

Comment: By the way, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: How would you solve this part of code to resolve vulnerability and do you have any example how to use PostgreSQL age function in c#, thanks